# Override CRA webpack config without ejecting (remove random numbers from media files)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-app-rewired

I need to remove generated random numbers from all **pdf** files names in my project. (for example license.pdf instead of license.3402bc5d.pdf)

I tried to use **react-app-rewired**.

file **config-overrides.js**:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module = {
    ...config.module, // copy all settings
    rules: [
      ...config.module.rules,
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test:/\.pdf$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { name: "static/media/[name].pdf"}
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  };
  return config;
};
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf = config.module.rules[1].oneOf.map((one) => {
    if (one.options && one.options.name && one.exclude) {
      one.exclude = [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/, /\.pdf$/];
    }
    return one;
  }).concat([
    {
      test:/\.pdf$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: { name: "/docs/[name].[ext]"}
    }
  ]);

  return config;
};
```